# Submit de form com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho esta função para verificar os campos de inscrição estadual e de CNPJ/CPF e se estiverem certo ele realiza o `submit`, só que no `submit`, ele não está respeitando o required dos campos informados no `ViewModel`

```
$('#FornecedorNovo').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "/Fornecedor/VerificaInscricao";
    var Insc = $("#InscricaoEstadual").val();
    var Tipo = $("#TipoPessoa").val();
    var Isento = $("#InscricaoIsento").prop('checked');
    var form = this,
        $form = $(form); // Salvamos o formulário atual em uma variável

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { insc: Insc, isento: Isento },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado == true) {
                $("#messageI").html(data.mensagem);
                if (data.mensagem != 'O campo Inscrição é obrigatório.') {
                    $("#InscricaoEstadual").val('');
                    $("#InscricaoEstadual").focus();
                }
            } else {
                var url1 = "/Fornecedor/VerificaDocumento";
                var Documento = $("#Documento").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: url1,
                    data: { documento: Documento, tipo: Tipo },
                    datatype: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.resultado == true) {
                            $("#message").html(data.mensagem);
                            $("#Documento").val('');
                            $("#Documento").focus();
                        }
                        else {
                            $form.off('submit').submit();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

O certo não seria ele fazer o submit somente se os campos estivessem corretos ? Pois se o campo Inscrição Estadual e Documento estão de acordo, ele envia de qualquer forma os dados.

Comment: O `required` não valida os campos, ele apenas força o usuário a digitar qualquer coisa.

Comment: Então mas eu preciso que eles sejam preenchidos, e desta forma, ignora.

Comment: vocês está chamando o submit no botão? usando required no input não funcionou?

Comment: Eu configuro desta forma: `[Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatorio.")]
        [StringLength(150)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }` no `dataannotations`

Comment: Ta usando algum framework: Laravel, Ionic, angular?

Comment: Não, trabalho com ASP CORE, e utilizei a `ViewModel` para informar o required, @adventistaam quando o campo não está preenchido, por exemplo o nome, que é `required`, mas os dois desta regra acima estão corretos, ele envia, ignorando o preenchimento obrigatório do campo.

Comment: você está checando a requisição do lado do asp com ModelState.IsValid?

Comment: @LucasMiranda isso.

Comment: ao meu ver o que tá acontecendo é que required checa só pra nulos, quando você pega com jquery o val ele vem vazio, mas não vem nulo ("")

Comment: Ele aparece as mensagens que o campo é obrigatório e envia normalmente, então creio que o problema não é este, só que como tem esta parte no código `$form.off('submit').submit();` ele esta ignorando os campos obrigatórios.

Comment: não vou conseguir te ajudar muito porque não está muito claro o que você quer fazer, com sua requisição, mas já adianto que esse emaranhado de requisições e chamar o form no fim assim está confuso, mas ainda assim acho que o problema está lá do lado do lado do asp, tenta adicionar no seu required isso aqui:
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false)]

Comment: Eu faço a validação no `dataannotations`, porém quando os dados desta `function` acima estão corretos e ele cai no `$form.off('submit').submit();` ele não valida os campos, mas se eu tiro esta parte, ou coloco só `return true;` ele valida os campos, mas não faz o submit.

Comment: eu vi que você faz a validação  com data annotation, mas você não colocou nada pra validar vazio

Comment: @LucasMiranda fiz o teste e ocorre a mesma coisa, nesta parte da função no `submit` eu não consigo verificar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, adicionando esta linha na parte do `submit`:

```
   if ($('#FornecedorNovo').valid()) {
         $form.off('submit').submit();
   }
```